# jQuery set child CSS attribute problem

Tags: jquery, css

I have a child element of a div named "bob" that's class is '.divTitle'

```
<div id="bob">
   <div class="divTitle">
      <a href="#">
         <h1>Title</h1>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to set the background color of "divTitle" to red but for the life of me can't get this to work.  Right now I am trying two things...

```
$('#bob').children('.divTitle')[0].css('background-color', '#0f0'); // assuming children is returning an array...
```

and

```
$('#bob').children('.divTitle').css('background-color', '#0f0');
```

neither with any success... can anyone tell me what I am missing here?  Do I have to go deeper than ".children"?

EDIT

Unfortunately, I guess the important part of this question was omitted.  I was generating this div dynamically, and making reference to the class was just coming up empty.  So, instead of referencing the dynamically generated interior div by class type, I gave it a unique id and now can manipulate it as I wish...  I'm still giving the check mark to Keltex for pointing out a better direct reference method.

Comment: Other than you're setting it to green?

Comment: You should try #f00 instead of #0f0...

Comment: that's just clerical... i'd be happy if it turned ANY color...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just:

```
$('#bob .divTitle').css('background-color', '#0f0');
```

Comment: The problem he's having is getting children() returns the actual DOM elements, whereas using the selector gives you back jQuery objects (which actually have a css method).  So you get my upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

The second should work fine. Your problem lies somewhere else.

First thing: are you executing this code when the document is ready loading/populating the elements of interest?

```
<head>
    ...
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#bob .divTitle').css('background-color', '#0f0');
        });
    </script>
</head>
...
```

If not, then do so, or move the script to *after* the DOM elements of interest.

```
...
<div id="bob">
   <div class="divTitle">
      <a href="#">
         <h1>Title</h1>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#bob .divTitle').css('background-color', '#0f0');
</script>
...
```

Comment: the div 'bob' is being generated dynamically after my document has loaded on a key press.  I am able to change the background color of 'bob' with no problem, I just can't figure out why I can't reach inside of bob and manipulate child elements...

Answer (score 0):

`$('#bob').children('.divTitle')[0]` <-- this is returning the dom object rather than the jQuery object which is why this one doesn't work.

The second one should work for you though, I've done what you have above as an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kNF5B/).